# Where should we save our html and php files while using bitnami wapp?

Tags: php, html, postgresql, xampp

Open application option is not working. Is that where we should save the files?

[image: screenshot]

Where are we supposed to store the PHP and HTML files?
   or,
What is the equivalent of htdocs (of xampp) in bitnami wapp?

Comment: image of  "bitnami wapp stack" manager is in the link.

Answer (score 2):

We have to store the HTML and PHP files in the htdocs folder. It is normally found at the directory where you installed it.

For example, `C:\Bitnami\wappstack-7.2.23-0\apache2\htdocs`.
This folder htdocs is equivalent to the htdocs in xampp.

Comment: What about open aplication option of wapp manager.(see image)?